# jQuery datatable ignores rows with colspan

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a table that looks like this:

EDITED:

```
<table id="results">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>NAME</th>
        <th>NUMBER</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#" onclick="$('#user_1').toggle();">1</a></td>
        <td>JOHN</td>
        <td>311-123-4523</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="user_1" class="hide">
        <td colspan="3">
        Some information about the user
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>    
</table>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#results').dataTable({
            "sPaginationType": "bootstrap"
        });
    });
</script>
```

Note: Clicking on the id number, show/hide the detail row.

I am having problems when dataTable try to render the table with the colspan, i get this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'asSorting' of undefined
```

If I remove the detail rows, datatable renders everything fine.

What i want to know if it is possible to tell dataTable to ignore details rows as described above.

Comment: what do you mean by ignore? disable or not-visible?

Comment: they're HTML tables with **data** in them. Not **Datatables**. Some people might get confused you know

Comment: When i try to do $('table').dataTable(); i get this error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'asSorting' of undefined  and its because of datatable is trying to sort with the table with colspans

Comment: a bit more insight (by insight i mean code) would be helpful :)

It might be better to see where youre making a mistake if we see ur code

Comment: Edited the question you may see a bit more code now!

Comment: trying to find out solution too :]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend to use this solution direct from datatable

[DataTables hidden row details example](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/row_details.html)

works great

Comment: Your solution did the job. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I read through the documentation of Datatable and it looks like doesnt support `colspan` as of now.

You might want to look at these links. They provide alternatives to `colspans`. This seems to be quite cumbersome, agreed, but as of now, there's no other go.

[Datatables forum link](http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/14/datatables-and-colspan/p1)

[SO link for a similar kind of question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199299/datatable-colspan-sorting)

**Edit :**

On reading more, i found [this](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/advanced_init/complex_header.html) :
This discusses on how colspan and sowspan can be used for grouping. Maybe you could look more at that.

And ensure that you're using the latest version of the plugin.

Comment: Thanks i think i'll use modal to display details instead of rows

Answer (score 0):

Add to your css:

```
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

and to onclick handler:

```
$('#user_1').toggleClass('hide');
```

Comment: class hide already exists my problem its with js datatable plugin